# Safety around old laptop batteries

Tags: batteries, safety, laptop

I found an old laptop with a removable battery that hasn't been used it (probably) years, maybe decades. I want to plug it in to see if it still works, but I'm not sure if it's safe to do so. I either try plugging it in without the battery installed and risk breaking it, or I plug it in with the battery and risk a fire hazard. Is an old battery likely to cause a fire if it's been unattended for years, and is there a risk of breaking the laptop if I try to power it on without a battery installed? It uses a Lithium-ion battery, but I don't know much besides that.

Comment: If it's that old, it's probably not lithium.   If it's not lithium it's NiCd or NiMH and they're pretty docile.

Comment: No matter how old it is, you could tell us the make and model number of the laptop ;-)

Answer (score 1):

There is always a risk with mishandled batteries.

However why would a laptop damage if used without battery? It either works fine without a battery or it doesn't work at all if it does require a battery.

Lithium batteries do degrade and damage when left discharged. Battery packs may have circuits that can detect that it is too discharged and disable the battery so it can't be used any more. So the pack may be just be unusable anyway.

Comment: Right. There laptops that are meant to work only with a working battery (I had an very old sony with NiCd-battery). Others like many IBM/Lenovo work without battery. If the battery is removeable without tools there is IMO very low risk to damage the laptop when trying to start it without battery.

Answer (score 0):

If you're worried, put it on top of something metal such as a baking tray when you charge it.

Comment: ... and place the tray so that there is air or something else below it that is heat resisting. Also, if the battery gets too hot to be touched, turn it off.